# No match with qi::repeat and optional parser

Tags: boost, boost-spirit

I've been experimenting with Qi to parse a simple, new-line delimited
file of vertices.  In the following format (expressed in my made-up easy to read notation):

`double double double optional(either (int int int optional(int)) or (double double double optional(double)))`

My test-cases start failing with `repeat` and I can't find the error. The comments in the code are hopefully more enlightening:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::spirit;

qi::rule<std::string::iterator, ascii::space_type> vertexRule = 
  (double_ >> double_ >> double_);

qi::rule<std::string::iterator, ascii::space_type> colorRule = 
  (double_ >> double_ >> double_ >> -(double_)) | (uint_ >> uint_ >> uint_ >> -(uint_));

template<typename Iterator, typename Rule>
bool parseIt(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Rule rule) {
  bool r = qi::phrase_parse(
    begin, end,
    rule,
    ascii::space
    );

  if(begin != end) {
    std::cout << "No full match!" << std::endl;
    while(begin != end)
      std::cout << *begin++;
    return false;
  }
  return r;
}

int main()
{
  qi::rule<std::string::iterator, ascii::space_type> rule1 =
    repeat(3)[vertexRule >> -(colorRule)];

  std::string t1{
    "20.0 20.0 20.0\n"
      "1.0 1.0 1.0 255 0 255 23\n"
      "1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.3 0.2 0.3\n"
        };
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  // matches
  std::cout << parseIt(t1.begin(), t1.end(), rule1) << std::endl;

  // 3 double 3 ints
  std::string test{"1.0 1.0 1.0 1 3 2\n"};
  // matches individually
  std::cout << parseIt(test.begin(), test.end(), vertexRule >> -(colorRule)) << std::endl;

  // offending line added at the end
  // but position does not matter
  // also offending 3 double 3 double
  std::string t2{
    "20.0 20.0 20.0\n"
      "1.0 1.0 1.0 255 0 255 23\n"
      "1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.3 0.2 0.3\n"
      "1.0 1.0 1.0 1 3 2\n"
      };

  qi::rule<std::string::iterator, ascii::space_type> rule2 =
    repeat(4)[vertexRule >> -(colorRule)];

  // does not match
  std::cout << parseIt(t2.begin(), t2.end(), rule2) << std::endl;

  // interestingly this matches
  // std::string t2{
  //     "1.0 1.0 1.0 1 3 2\n"
  //     "1.0 1.0 1.0 1 3 2\n"
  //     "1.0 1.0 1.0 1 3 2\n"
  //     "1.0 1.0 1.0 1 3 2\n"
  //     };
}
```

I'm new to parser construction and especially Boost.Spirit. So comments pointing out the obvious are also appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your *prose description* and sample inputs seem to indicate line-ends have significance to your grammar.

Yet, I cannot find any evidence of the fact that you tried to express that in your rules.

There is one other issue with the ambiguity between `double_` and `uint_` (see below).

Here is a reworked sample that adds a custom skipper (that will no *eat* the `eol`). Also, I made it accept any number of trailing `eol`, but nothing else:

```
skipper = qi::char_(" \t");

bool r = qi::phrase_parse(
             begin, end,
             (vertexRule >> -colorRule) % qi::eol >> *qi::eol >> qi::eoi,
             skipper
         );
```

Full code returning success for all parses:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::spirit;

template<typename Iterator>
bool parseIt(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    qi::rule<Iterator, qi::blank_type> vertexRule, colorRule;

    vertexRule = double_ >> double_ >> double_;
    colorRule  = (double_ >> double_ >> double_ >> -(double_)) | (uint_ >> uint_ >> uint_ >> -(uint_));

    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(
                 begin, end,
                 (vertexRule >> -colorRule) % qi::eol >> *qi::eol >> qi::eoi,
                 qi::blank
             );

    if(begin != end)
    {
        std::cout << "No full match! '" << std::string(begin, end) << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    std::string t1
    {
        "20.0 20.0 20.0\n"
        "1.0 1.0 1.0 255 0 255 23\n"
        "1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.3 0.2 0.3\n"
    };
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    // matches
    std::cout << parseIt(t1.begin(), t1.end()) << std::endl;

    // 3 double 3 ints
    std::string test {"1.0 1.0 1.0 1 3 2\n"};
    // matches individually
    std::cout << parseIt(test.begin(), test.end()) << std::endl;

    // offending line added at the end
    // but position does not matter
    // also offending 3 double 3 double
    std::string t2
    {
        "20.0 20.0 20.0\n"
        "1.0 1.0 1.0 255 0 255 23\n"
        "1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.3 0.2 0.3\n"
        "1.0 1.0 1.0 1 3 2\n"
    };

    // does not match
    std::cout << parseIt(t2.begin(), t2.end()) << std::endl;

    // interestingly this matches
    // std::string t2{
    //     "1.0 1.0 1.0 1 3 2\n"
    //     "1.0 1.0 1.0 1 3 2\n"
    //     "1.0 1.0 1.0 1 3 2\n"
    //     "1.0 1.0 1.0 1 3 2\n"
    //     };
}
```

#### `uint_` versus `double_`

As mentioned, there is also an ambiguity lurking here:

```
colorRule  = (double_ >> double_ >> double_ >> -(double_)) | (uint_ >> uint_ >> uint_ >> -(uint_));
```

As it stands, the `(uint_ >> uint_ >> uint_ >> -(uint_)` part of the rule will never be matched, as it would also match the first part (with `double_`). I'd simply rewrite this as

```
colorRule  = double_ >> double_ >> double_ >> -double_;
```

Unless of course the meaning of the values changes if they are specified as floats (e.g. uints go from 0..255, but doubles go from 0.0..1.0). In that case I can see why you would want to detect integer-ness. You can achieve that by reordering.

```
colorRule  = (uint_ >> uint_ >> uint_ >> -(uint_))
           | (double_ >> double_ >> double_ >> -(double_));
```

To make things easier on the user of the parser, I'd simply expose the same attribute type at all times, and consider a semantic action to convert the integers to doubles using whatever conversion appropriate:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
// ....

qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper, double()> colorInt = uint_ [ _val = _1 / 255.0 ];
colorRule = (colorInt >> colorInt >> colorInt >> -(colorInt))
           | (double_ >> double_ >> double_ >> -(double_));
```

Comment: I was under the impression that the new-lines are handled automatically as it seemed to work in most runs. Apparently I was wrong. Skipping is still one of the darkest areas of spirit for me.

Comment: @pmr: Skipping is actually too simple; most people expect it to do magic, but it doesn't: skippers will simply skip _all_ skippables (whitespace, most often) before the parsers ever see the input. Look at `qi::lexeme[]` (to disable skipping for an expression),  `qi::raw[]` (to return raw source iterators, including skipped chars) , `qi::distinct` (from the Spirit Repository -- to require skips at parser boundaries) to manage skippers. Note that to user e.g. `colorInt` inside `qi::lexeme[]` you'll have to remove the Skipper from the rule type :)

Comment: One more thing: By staying away from skippers you mean: Mention each skipped token in the rule and use `qi::parse` instead of `qi::parse_phrase`?